# Create 16 byte key for AES Encryption from Salt and Password in Node JS Crypto

Tags: node.js, encryption, aes, cryptojs, aescryptoserviceprovider

I'm trying to match an AES 256 CBC encryption implemented in C# by using node JS crypto module.

This is my C# code

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography; 
using System.Text;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(EncryptExt("Hello World"));
        Console.WriteLine(DecryptExt(EncryptExt("Hello World")));
    }

    public static string EncryptExt(string raw)

        {

            using (var csp = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())

            {

                ICryptoTransform e = GetCryptoTransformExt(csp, true);

                byte[] inputBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(raw);

                byte[] output = e.TransformFinalBlock(inputBuffer, 0, inputBuffer.Length);



                string encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(output);



                return encrypted;

            }

        }



        public static string DecryptExt(string encrypted)

        {

            using (var csp = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())

            {

                var d = GetCryptoTransformExt(csp, false);

                byte[] output = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);

                byte[] decryptedOutput = d.TransformFinalBlock(output, 0, output.Length);



                string decypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedOutput);

                return decypted;

            }

        }



        private static ICryptoTransform GetCryptoTransformExt(AesCryptoServiceProvider csp, bool encrypting)

        {

            csp.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

           csp.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            var passWord = Convert.ToString("AvbSkj3BVbf4o6mdlAofDp0/SD0susEWo0pKdmqas");

            var salt = Convert.ToString("ABj4PQgf3j5gblQ0iDp0/Gb07ukQWo0a");



            String iv = Convert.ToString("aAB1jhPQ89o=f619");



            var spec = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passWord), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt), 65536);

            byte[] key = spec.GetBytes(16);





            csp.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(iv);

            csp.Key = key;

            if (encrypting)

            {

                return csp.CreateEncryptor();

            }

            return csp.CreateDecryptor();

        }

}
```

And this is my Node JS implementation

```
const crypto = require('crypto'),
  algorithm = 'aes-128-cbc',
  password = 'AvbSkj3BVbf4o6mdlAofDp0/SD0susEWo0pKdmqas',
  salt = 'ABj4PQgf3j5gblQ0iDp0/Gb07ukQWo0a',
  iv = 'aAB1jhPQ89o=f619',
  inputEncoding = 'utf8',
  outputEncoding = 'base64';


 function encrypt(text) {
  let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm,createHashPassword(), iv);
  let encrypted = cipher.update(text, inputEncoding, outputEncoding)
  encrypted += cipher.final(outputEncoding);
  return encrypted;
}

function createHashPassword(){
    let nodeCrypto = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(Buffer.from(password), Buffer.from(salt), 65536, 16, 'sha1');

    return nodeCrypto || nodeCrypto.toString('hex');
};

function decrypt(encrypted) {
  let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, Buffer.from(createHashPassword(),"hex"), iv)
  let dec = decipher.update(encrypted, outputEncoding, inputEncoding)
  dec += decipher.final(inputEncoding);
  return dec;
}

console.log(encrypt('Hello World'));
console.log(decrypt(encrypt('Hello World')));
```

The encrypted data from both this  options are coming different hence, not able to work this out.

So far what I have seen is,

- node crypto createCipheriv method takes only 32 byte buffer and if I
  pass it a 16 byte buffer it says, invalid length.
- If I convert the 16 byte key to hex encoded string, the encrypted value changes and does not match with the C# implementation.
- I can't change the C# implementation as its already in production and been used by multiple applications.
- So there seems to be an issue with generating key from salt and password in node js, matching what is done in C# and I'm not able to figure that out.

Code can be tested in the below link:
C# Implementation: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bClrpW
Node JS Implementation: https://runkit.com/a-vi-nash/5c062544509d8200156f6111

Comment: I need to analyze your code completely(which is not easy), but there is a obvious error in your code at least. `AES256` keylen is 32 bytes, but you are using 16 byte keylen in your `C#` code. so at least there is a bug here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are creating a `AES-128` instance in your `C#` code, because you are using 16 bytes keylen.

`AES-256` keylen is 32 bytes, not 16 bytes.

Bugs in code:

1. Since you set 16 bytes for key in `C#`, it uses `AES-128`, not `AES-256`. So you need to change `node.js` to `AES-128` or change generated key to 32 bytes in both sides.
2. Since you are using text string salt and password(not `base64` encoded), your `node.js` side uses incorrect `pbkdf2Sync` parameters.
3. `IV` len for `AES` algorithm in 16 bytes and you cannot use shorter ones.

Since you wanted `AES-256` here are your changed to both sides:

**`C#` side:**

```
String iv = Convert.ToString("SOME_IV_SOME_IV_"); // 16 bytes IV
....
byte[] key = spec.GetBytes(32); // 32 bytes key
```

**`node.js` side:**

```
iv = 'SOME_IV_SOME_IV_' // 16 bytes IV similar to C#
...
// Bugs in this function
function createHashPassword(){
    // Change parameters to `base64` only if salt and password are base64. it may be true for salt, but it is can rarely be correct for password.
    let nodeCrypto = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(Buffer.from(password), Buffer.from(salt), 65536, 32, 'sha1');

    return nodeCrypto;
};
```

**IMPORTANT NOTES:**

1. Remember that `IV` must be selected as a random buffer(neither fixed not text) and since it seems that you are sending it over network, you need to send `IV` with it too.
2. `SALT` must be a random buffer(not text) and fixed on both sides.
3. i suggest to use over 100000 iteration for `PBKDF2` at least.

Comment: Hey Afshin,
I tried changing the algorithm to aes-128-cbc in my node js but the resultant encrypted value is not matching with the C# one.

Comment: @Avinash updated answer with your bugs and recommendations. I checked and with these change it will work.

Comment: it works, I changed the encryption to AES-128 and crypto.pbkdf2Sync parameters.
Thanks a ton. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you operate with passwords of 41 characters length, **why don't you instead use an actual key?** A base64 encoded 256 bit key would be 44 characters long.

The purpose of the salt and the iteration for the deviation is to counter the common problem of too short passwords. But why go through all the bother of implementering this in both ends with no added benefits, but more than one disadvantages - like more code & slower solution.

Comment: This is something I have suggested my client, but they have this rigid implementation which they don't want to change.